# I still love to read his punchlines but yaa.. no feelings are included

Tags: grammar

Which one should I use?

1. No feelings are included
2. No feelings is included
3. No feeling is included?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to say.  Whose feelings are they? Yours? His? And what do you mean by "included"?

Answer (score 1):

> No feelings is included

This is not grammatical. "feelings" is plural, while "is" is singular.

> No feeling is included?

Probably not, because it appears you are trying to make a statement, rather than ask a  question. A question mark indicates a question.

> No feelings are included.

This is grammatical. It's the best choice of the three.

However, it still doesn't make sense. Feelings are not "included" like batteries. Usually, you would "have" feelings.  Here are some alternatives:

> I still love to read his punchlines, but I don't feel anything anymore.
>   I still love to read his punchlines, but I don't feel anything now.
>   I still love to read his punchlines... but I don't feel anything.

However, it still doesn't clearly make sense. The word "feelings" usually refers to emotions like happiness, sadness, anger.  "Punchlines" refer to comedy, where the statement would be "I don't find them funny anymore."  Mostly likely (although not necessarily) you'd discuss laughing, or thinking something was funny, instead of feelings.